# How to store loaded value in JS?

Tags: javascript

I've got this statement:

```
$('#queueCount').load("http://localhost:8081/smsc/userRole/getQueueCount/");
```

`#queueCount` is a `<div>` id.  How can I store loaded value in variable? For example, like this:

```
var value=$('#queueCount').load("http://localhost:8081/smsc/userRole/getQueueCount/");
```

Comment: I bet everything you need to know is here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways.. (1st and 2nd preffered)

```
var vardata;
$.get('http://localhost:8081/smsc/userRole/getQueueCount/', function(data) {
    vardata = data;
});
```

or

```
var vardata;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/smsc/userRole/getQueueCount/',
    success: function(data) {
        vardata = data;
    }
});
```

or

```
var vardata;
$('#queueCount').load("http://localhost:8081/smsc/userRole/getQueueCount/");
vardata = $('#queueCount').html();
```

Comment: #2 and #3 won't work properly. 2 won't add the data to the element, #3 won't have loaded in time.

Comment: yeah, in the 3rd one if i will chain them it will work i guess..

var vardata=$('#queueCount').load("http://localhost:8081/smsc/userRole/getQueueCount/").html();

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hjggsqx2/2/

This is how I'd do it. I also like the syntax [website] [classname/id name]. It is more convenient.

```
var $div = $('<div>');
alert($div);

$div.load('http://www.aligajani.com .container', function(){
    // now $(this) contains .container
});
```